# i have a confusion regarding the following code in c

Tags: arrays, c, function

//for the 1st code to print the value, we are using *ptr.

```
#include<stdio.h>
   int main(){
   int aadhar[5];
   int *ptr = &aadhar[0];

   printf("enter the numers");
   for(int i=0; i<5;i++){
    scanf("%d",(ptr+i));
   }
    for(int i=0; i<5;i++){
    printf("%d\n",*(ptr+i));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

but for the following code here, for printing we are not using * arr[I] or *ptr[i]. instead, we are using arr[i] or ptr[i].. what is the reason for that?

```
#include<stdio.h>

void printnumber( int arr[], int n);

int main(){
    int arr[]={1,2,3,4,5,6};
    printnumber(arr,6);
    return 0;

}
void printnumber(int *ptr, int n){
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        printf("%d\t",ptr[i]);  //why we are not using *ptr[i]?

    }
}
```

Comment: `*(ptr+i)` is the same as `ptr[i]`.

Comment: `*ptr[i]` is an error, which you can see if you try it.

Comment: @PaulHankin was probable an attempt to make that part **bold** with an asterisk `*`-

Answer (score 2):

This is because, `*(ptr+i)` is the same as `ptr[i]`. They are the same.

`*ptr[i]` does not make sense here, as `ptr[i]` is of type `int`, not a pointer that you can use the unary `*` operator on. Quoting chapter 6.5.3.2,

> *The operand of the unary `*` operator shall have pointer type.*

Comment: but when I use ptr[i] in the 1st code, it is showing the address of ptr, not the value.